# ASP.Net MVC Core 1.0, how avoid reencoding characters from inside a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

characters from inside a view are misencoded by the razor renderer. for instance:

MyPartial.cshtml: `á á á`

MyView.cshtml:  `á á á @Html.Partial("_MyPartial")`

The final output is rendered as `á á á � � �`

Is this an expected behaviour?

Comment: Are the files saved with proper encodings?

Comment: ok, file encoding was the problem, problem solved =)